# Is writing plug in for eclipse dependent on operating system?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

we start to write plug in for eclipse to work with some java frame work like hadoop (we want to edit hadoop eclipse plug in and merge it with other. our plug in must work in Linux operating system. Generally writing plug in for eclipse depend on operating system or not? if depend what benefits to write it for Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the previous answer is correct... in most cases. You should specifically check all the interfaces with the operating system.

SWT is a Java wrapper over native OS  widgets. It behaves almost the same on all OSs, but not exactly. There are subtleties. For example, events that might be fired a bit differently, drawing of widgets, etc. My experience shows that you have to check on all OSs to be sure that it works as it should, especially if you are doing more complex UI rendering. In many cases I had to do some fine tuning to get it right. It is not a great deal of effort, but it should be considered.

Another issue is working with the file system. For example, make sure you are composing files paths correctly. It is always a good idea to test that part as well.

Comment: By all means test on all platforms you would like to support. In my experience, Mac OS X is especially prone to UI problems because of its rounded buttons and other eye candy. Very good point regarding file system differences, obviously this applies for non-Eclipse Java code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse plugins are platform independent (you are writing them in Java), unless your plugin requires some low-level calls to the operating system (i.e. JNI) or to invoke some tool found only in the Linux OS.
The only part of Eclipse tied - in part - to the OS is the SWT toolkit, since it's optimized for the graphic environment you are running it, but if Eclipse can run in the OS you are interested in, you should not be bothered by this.